# How to search through a webpage to find a certain text

Tags: java, terminal

I am currently writing a java program that is something similar to a cookbook. I have everything built, but unfortunately, I have no recipes.

I searched around and found http://allrecipes.com/. I had looked at the source and found lines that contained the ingredients, the recipes, nutritional facts.

I remember using `grep` in terminal, and I quickly found `lynx` to be useful. This is what I have so far (for a sample page).

To get 100 lines after the first mention of Ingredients: `lynx -dump "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Potato-Crunchy-Tenders/" | grep -n -A 100 "Ingredients"`

To get the line number of the "Ingredients": `lynx -dump "http://allrecipes.com/Recipe/Beef-Tips-and-Noodles/" |  grep -n "Ingredients" | cut -f1 -d:`

I have done a few examples and have found that the recipes start 6 lines after the "Ingredients" line, and a new ingredient is every other line, like so:

"135:Ingredients [66]Edit and Save

136-

137-   Original recipe makes 6 servings [67]Change Servings

138-   Makes 6___________________ servings (*) US ( ) Metric [68]Adjust Recipe

139-   ([69]Help)

140-     * [ ]

141-       1/2 cup vegetable oil for frying

142-     * [ ]

143-       1 1/2 cups milk

144-     * [ ]

145-       1 egg

146-     * [ ]

147-       1 (7.6 ounce) package garlic flavored instant mashed potatoes
"

My goal is to somehow get just the ingredients in a text file that I can parse with java (Which I am comfortable with). I hope to do the same thing with the recipe.

This way, I can do this automatically for many recipes so I don't have to get all of these by hand.

Is there a way to do this in java that is easier?

Cheers.

Comment: You will probably want to parse the html of the website, and tools like jsoup can help you. If this were my project, I'd Google this, download it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I looked into JSoup, and it has worked perfectly.

I have ironed out as many kinks as I could tonight, and here is the code I have come up with.

To get a `listOfIngredients` (extends `ArrayList<Ingredient>`):

public static ListOfIngredients getListOfIngredients(final String html) {

```
    ListOfIngredients tmp = new ListOfIngredients();
    try {
        Element body = Jsoup.connect(html).get().body();

        try {
            for (Element elem : body.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "ingredients")) {
                Elements ingredientAmtElements = elem.getElementsByClass("ingredient-amount");
                String amount = null;
                if (!ingredientAmtElements.isEmpty()) {
                    amount = ingredientAmtElements.first().text();
                }
                String ingredient = elem.getElementsByClass("ingredient-name").first().text();
                if (!ingredient.equals("\u00a0")) {
                    tmp.add(new Ingredient(amount, ingredient));
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

To get the `Instructions` (extends `ArrayList<String>`):

`public static Instructions getInstructions(final String html) {
        Instructions instr = new Instructions();
        try {
            Element body = Jsoup.connect(html).get().body();
            Element elem = body.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "recipeInstructions").first();
            for (Element e : elem.getElementsByTag("li")) {
                instr.add(e.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return instr;
    }`